# When did Windows last resume from standby or hibernate?

Tags: vba

Is there any way (like an api) in VBA, to determine when Windows last resumed from standby, etc.?
I am not trying to fire an event, just be able to look up the time when I need it.

Comment: Give a clearer explanation of what you mean and support it with relevant examples.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your requirements (not trying to fire an event),I should tell you can not do that. Althogh [this link](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=306116) may help you

Edits:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, AddressOf mypmc
    End Sub

    Public Sub mypmc(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PowerModeChangedEventArgs)
Dim iFileNum As Integer     'File number for output text file.
strOutputFile = "c:\log.txt"
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open strOutputFile For Output As #iFileNum

        If e.Mode = PowerModes.Suspend Then
          Print #1, "Suspending" &  TimeValue(Now)
        End If
        If e.Mode = PowerModes.Resume Then
             Print #1, "Resuming" &  TimeValue(Now)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Link only answers are strongly frowned upon as the link may due in the future and a future reader won't know what was suggested.  I would edit your answer to include some important elements from that link that would be helpful on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had found that post. I don't want a notification. I simply want to be able to determine when the machine last resumed from standby, etc. I have an Access app with ODBC linked tables. If the machine goes into standby and resumes, while the app is open, the ODBC connection is no longer valid. This generates many errors. When I catch the error, if I can determine that the machine resumed from standby after the app was opened, I can notify the user and close the app.

Comment: Thanks David, unfortunately, I need something that will work in VBA. Adding a .NET assembly is not an option.